# infinite loop while generating Fibonacci series in asm8086

Tags: assembly, fibonacci, emu8086

my code is to generate the elements of Fibonacci series based on the number given by user .. the thing is that whenever i input any number , it goes into an infinite loop other than outputting the certain no. elements i input .. and here is the procedure i use to print out the Fibonacci sequence :

```
displayFib proc
MOV DX, 30h         ; move value 30 hexadecimal to DX, which represents 0
call display
MOV AX, input   
CMP AX, 0        ;if the input is 0 in hexadecimal ASCII value then jump to finish
JE finish_it

mov   ah,9              ; formating - coma
mov   dx,offset msg3
int   21h       

;display the 1st term
MOV DX, 31h         ; move value 31 hexadecimal to DX, which represents 1
call display
CMP input, 1        ;if the input is 1 in hexadecimal ASCII value then jump to finish
JE finish_it

MOV CX, input       ;intializing counter, knowing that first 2 terms were displayed already
SUB CX, 2

repeat:
    mov   ah,9              ; formating - coma
    mov   dx,offset msg3
    int   21h       

    MOV AX, fibn_2        ; calculating the n'th term of a sequence    n = (n-1) + (n-2) 
    ADD AX, fibn_1
    MOV fib, AX
    MOV DX, fib
    MOV saveCount, CX       ;saving the state of the counter as it will be modified in the displayNum
    call displayNum
    ;display the n'th term (current term)
    MOV CX, saveCount       ;restoring state of the counter
    MOV AX, fibn_1        ; n-1 in the next round of a loop will be n-2
    MOV fibn_2, AX
    MOV AX, fib         ;n'th term in the next round will be n-1
    MOV fibn_1, AX
    DEC  CX             ;decrementing counter
    JNZ repeat          ; loop until counter = 0

finish_it:

ret
displayFib endp
```

- I am using emu8086
- [here](http://ideone.com/iS9aB4) is my fully-written code if needed

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't used the emulator to step through the code, have you?

Comment: Yes I have but i cannot find where the error is so far as am still a beginner and that's almost my first code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> MOV CX, input       ;intializing counter, knowing that first 2 terms were displayed already
> SUB CX, 2
> ```

What happens when *input* is 2? An infinite loop!!!

---

Your program fails because you don't treat the input in the correct way!

The *keyin* routine destroys the `AH` register, yet you move the `AX` register to the *num1* variable. Correct by explicitely zeroing the `AH` register.

```
call keyin     ;gets user input
SUB AL, 48     ;changes ASCII value into numeric value for further processing

mov ah, 0      <<<<<<< ADD THIS

mov num1 , AX  ;saves user input to variable num1
```

The same goes for the *num2* variable.

---

> ```
> MOV saveCount, CX       ;saving the state of the counter as it will be modified in the displayNum
> call displayNum         ;display the n'th term (current term)
> MOV CX, saveCount       ;restoring state of the counter
> ```

Whatever happened to pushing/popping?

```
PUSH CX             ;saving the state of the counter as it will be modified in the displayNum 
call displayNum     ;display the n'th term (current term)
POP CX              ;restoring state of the counter
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed solution :) .. But unfortunately i still have the same problem ..